# Lua continue script execution

Tags: lua, swig

I have a config file from a previous version of my software, the config file is basically a Lua script. I'm using swig to generate the wrapper to interface with the C API of my software.

The problem that I'm having is that some instructions in the previous config file was removed in the current version of the software.

When I load and run the Lua file the execution stop at the first error and the rest of the config file is not executed.

How can I make Lua report an error and continue the script execution at the next instruction?

Comment: BTW, it's Lua not LUA. It's not an acronym, just to give you a heads up.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [the error handling section in the Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.3)
(look here [for version5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.7) ).

It all boils down to putting the "sensitive" code into a function and call it with `pcall`.

More info on handling errors [in Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html)

Comment: Im using the following code:

    if( luaL_dostring( L, code ) )
    {
      printf( "error:%s\n", lua_tostring( L, -1 ) );

      lua_pop( L, 1 );
    }

Once an error is encountered how can I give the go to resume/continue with the next Lua instruction in the variable code (which is quite a huge block), after the error. I can't really parse the Lua instructions in the  variable code since there is some if, function etc... I really have to tell Lua to continue the execution of the script even if an error is found. Is this possible?

Comment: No. Like that it's not possible. You should wrap the code that can error in a `pcall`. Once an error occures, it's only logical Lua can't continue executing the chunk, and it will drop out of the `pcall`. Execution will be resumed only after the `pcall`. So you need to dive into the Lua code.